# WordPress redirection chaos

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, redirects

I have a problem regarding redirection.

It started out as I noticed, my non-www version is redirected to the www version by 302 redirect. Since then, I am trying to figure out why this is happening. I'm using WordPress 3.3.1. The htacces contains the correct, but it seems to be ignored. (At least if I change the RewriteRule to a completely different tld, nothing happens.)

I tried adding

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

and I tried using the explicit version putting in the URL (www.dreadfactory.de by the way).

While trying to narrow down what the source of this error may be, I discovered, that every link starting with the non-www version is redirectet via 302 to the root www version. So if I call `dreadfactory.de/angebot` it redirects to `www.dreadfactory.de`.

I deactivated every plugin, one by one, and I changed themes. I updated / reset the WordPress permalink stuff and I tried A LOT of different htaccess versions, but the error still remains the same: a 302 redirect where ther should be a 301 redirect.

Since this page is the only page in my webpackage (Hosteurope) with a subdomain, my theory was that maybe the hoster has some differences in his serversetting for domains with subdomains that are not compatible with something I'm doing, but even after deactivating subdomains, the problem still remained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the DNS entries, it could be that your host configured your DNS in an unusual way.

What happens without any htaccess in place?

//update

In this case it turned out that Marvin's naked domain and www domain were pointing at different ip's or servers adjusting the DNS settings in the ISP's control panel solved the problem.

Comment: If I remove the htaccess file, the permalinks don't work anymore. The only thing working without the file is the root page, since the dynamic pages are not rewritten properly anymore.

Comment: Once you've removed the file, reset permalinks to the default option, if that's working properly we might be able to troubleshoot properly. Did you look at the DNS?

Comment: Ok, I reset the permalinks to the default option. The issue stays exactly the same, the only difference is the ?=id form of the urls. 
The DNS lookup via Kloth.net:
' DNS server handling your query: ns1.hans.hosteurope.de
 DNS server's address: 217.115.143.140#53
 
 Name: www.dreadfactory.de
 Address: 80.237.133.31'

Comment: Its the DNS settings in your ISP's control panel you need to look up you seem to have something on your naked domain that you don't on your www. domain. Have you asked your host's support about the problem. I'm hitting the sack - will pick up again in the morning.

Comment: Well, the only thing that's different to the other working domains in this package is, that there seems to be a host-sided entry for the "webapplication" wordpress 3.0
Maybe that's the error. Maybe the host has scripts/entries of it's own for this application. I will have to consult the support for this in the morning and get back to you on this one afterwards. :)

Comment: Well, I can rule out the host-application. It is removed and had no impact at all.  
My hoster told me to use iptools to look up the DNS entries... 
[DNS for dreadfactory.de](http://www.iptools.com/dnstools.php?tool=dns&user_data=dreadfactory.de&type=A)  
[DNS for www.dreadfactory.de](http://www.iptools.com/dnstools.php?tool=dns&user_data=www.dreadfactory.de&type=A)

Comment: The IP address in the answer section should match - it appears to me that your naked domain and www. domain are pointing at different servers, or at the very least different IP's - I would take that information back to your hosting provider and find out why, before going any further with redirection.

Comment: Ok, I managed to change the entries. Now both Domains point to the same IP.
The redirect is still not working, but it's a step in the right direction :D

Comment: Glad that helped. Let me know if you need help with the redirection.

Comment: This actually resolved all the redirection issues. It's no doing a proper 301 redirect. :)